# Threejs fbx loader add objects to scene but i they aren't on the children array

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera, loader, fbx

Following the threejs.org FBX loader example, i got my model to be loaded with this function:

```
this.obj = null;

var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
var objs = []

function load_init( object ) {
    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( object );

    console.log("pushing to objs...");
    objs.push(object);
    console.log(objs[0]);

    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child.isMesh ) {
        //console.log(child)

        //console.log(child.material.length)

        const oldMat = child.material;
        var newMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();

        // if(oldMat.length == undefined)
        // {
        //     console.log(newMat.copy(oldMat));

        //     child.material = newMat;

        //     child.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {  
        //     color: oldMat.color,
        //     } );
        // }
        // else
        // {
        //     for(var i = 0; i < oldMat.length; i++)
        //     {
        //         child.material[i] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {  
        //         color: oldMat[i].color,
        //         } );
        //     }
            // }
        }
    } );

    object.position.z -= 200;
    object.position.y -= 250;
    var action = mixer.clipAction( object.animations[ 0 ] );
    action.play();
    scene.add( object );
} 

var true_load = load_init.bind(this);
console.log("printing objects...");
loader.load( 'Anims/Capoeira.fbx', true_load);

console.log(objs);//seems to have things there
console.log(objs[0]);//prints undefined
```

This adds the object succesfully and i can see the animation playing.
The problem is: I need to access the object loaded to the scene and mess around with it's variables(mostly material shading and color).
When i do `console.log(scene.children)` i can see it printing all the children. There are 4 total (A light, a ground, a grid helper and the loaded object). However, when i print the length, it'll only say there's 3 objects and if i try to access the loaded object directly through the children array or by getting the object by ID or name, i'll get undefined. I've also tried to change the function to return the loaded object and even set a variable called loaded_object, but i'll leave the function unfedined aswell.

Comment: You might want to consider adding `object` to another variable declared outside the `load_init` function.

Comment: I've tried to it with an array. The object seems to be inside it, but the same thing that happens with scene seems to be happening with this array. The object seems to be there, but i can't access it.
Printing the array gets me the object on the list, but when i try to access it on the position it should be, "there's nothing".

Comment: How are you trying to access it exactly? Can you add that code to your answer?

Comment: Just edited it(again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `THREE.LoadingManager`. These issues are most likely due to the asynchronous nature of the `loader.load` method.

In the `THREE.LoadingManager.onLoad` method, you should be able to access everything correctly.

Comment: Yes. everythings fine now.